# Keep Session alive for x amount of request then close it?

Tags: c#, proxy, connection

I'm using a proxy service which allows me to get a new ip on each request I make trough their proxy system. It's working fine, but I need to set the `keepalive` to false in my `HttpWebRequest`, else c# is going to use the connection which was created before again, which leads into using the same connection/proxy over and over again. I would love to send 3 requests over one "session/proxy" and then close it so the next `HttpWebRequest` won't use the same connection again, but I'm not too sure how I should realize that.

The code shown below will open a new connection to the proxy system each time I call the function:

```
Uri site = new Uri("https://randomsitehere/");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site);
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyURI, true, null, credentials);
request.UserAgent = "";
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.Method = "GET";
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    string responsex = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    string tokens = responsex.Split(new[] { @"""ip"": """ }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('"')[0];
    Console.WriteLine("Thread " + i +": "+tokens);
}
```

What I'm trying to archive looks like this:

request number 1 with a new proxy
request number 2 with the proxy used above / connection
request number 3 with the same proxy used above / connection
close the connection to the proxy
start again from the beginning

Is there any way to realize that?